# Coldfusion intermittent duplication on form submission!! Even with delete and update

Tags: sql-server, forms, coldfusion

I have been working on this for about 6 hours now....I don't have the slightest idea what is wrong.  I have a shopping cart of sorts with form variables for each item to update their quantity.  For whatever reason, completely at random, ColdFusion will insert two records for the form update. I even removed the update and went to putting a "DELETE ALL WHERE" query right above the insert statement just to make sure everything was cleared from the database, no luck.  Here's a look at my code (reverted to an update statement):

```
<cfquery datasource="something" result="UpdateProdRecordBase">
Update dbo.CS
SET dbo.CS.Quantity = <cfqueryparam value="#form['base#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#group#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#']#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
WHERE
dbo.CS.The_Product_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#">
AND dbo.CS.The_TRequestSubSet_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#TRSS#"> 
AND dbo.CS.ConfigType = 1 
AND dbo.CS.Group = <cfqueryparam value="#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"> 
AND dbo.CS.The_ParentProduct_ID = 0
</cfquery>


<cfif (isdefined("UpdateProdRecordBase.recordcount") AND UpdateProdRecordBase.recordcount EQ 0) OR (not isdefined("UpdateProdRecordBase.recordcount"))>
```

```
INSERT INTO dbo.CS(The_TRequestSubSet_ID, The_Product_ID, Quantity, ConfigType, Group)
VALUES (<cfqueryparam value="#TRSS#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">, 
<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#">, 
<cfqueryparam value="#form  ['base#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#group#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#']#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">, 
 1,<cfqueryparam value="#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">)
```

Again, these are back to back queries...99.9% of the time it works perfectly.  The other .1% of the time, it will duplicate the entry.  There is NO logical consistency to this.  I've also removed the update script in the past and added a delete query above the insert query.  Same luck.

For consistency sake, I've tested the same product combination multiple times.  You select the products, once time, works perfectly.  Select the same combination of products another time, a duplicate is inserted.

Any thoughts?  I'm completely out of options at this point.  I've outputted the queries during this process and there is no noticeable items making this happen, the data is exactly the same.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but does your code reside a function by any chance? The sporadic behavior sounds like the type of problems encountered due to lack of proper `var` scoping. As an aside, is there a reason you are using IsDefined on the `result` attribute? It should always exist.

Comment: Did you check your http logs to see if the page is running twice?

Answer (score 1):

I find that adding an `if not exists` before all of my inserts prevents all dups from various reasons ( most common being the user mashing the submit button lol. Try this :

```
 <cfquery>
    if not exists (select The_TRequestSubSet_ID 
        from  dbo.cs
        WHERE   The_TRequestSubSet_ID = <cfqueryparam value="#TRSS#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
          AND   The_Product_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#">
          AND   ConfigType = <cfqueryparam value="#form  ['base#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#group#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#']#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
          AND   Group = <cfqueryparam value="#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
                    )
    INSERT INTO dbo.CS(The_TRequestSubSet_ID , The_Product_ID, Quantity, ConfigType, Group)
    VALUES (<cfqueryparam value="#TRSS#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">, 
    <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#">, 
    <cfqueryparam value="#form  ['base#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#group#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#']#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">, 
     1,<cfqueryparam value="#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">)
    </cfquery>
```

This tells SQL to only insert the record if it doesn't already exists. And if you really want to make things easier:

```
<cfquery>
if not exists (select The_TRequestSubSet_ID 
                from  dbo.cs
                WHERE   The_TRequestSubSet_ID = <cfqueryparam value="#TRSS#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
                  AND   The_Product_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#">
                  AND   ConfigType = <cfqueryparam value="#form  ['base#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#group#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#']#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
                  AND   Group = <cfqueryparam value="#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
                )
    begin
        INSERT INTO dbo.CS(The_TRequestSubSet_ID, The_Product_ID, Quantity, ConfigType, Group)
        VALUES (<cfqueryparam value="#TRSS#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">, 
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#">, 
        <cfqueryparam value="#form  ['base#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#group#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#']#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">, 
         1,<cfqueryparam value="#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">)
    end
else 
    begin
        Update dbo.CS
        SET dbo.CS.Quantity = <cfqueryparam value="#form['base#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#group#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#']#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric">
        WHERE
        dbo.CS.The_Product_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#ConfigurationList.The_Product_ID#">
        AND dbo.CS.The_TRequestSubSet_ID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#TRSS#"> 
        AND dbo.CS.ConfigType = 1 
        AND dbo.CS.Group = <cfqueryparam value="#CurrentProductReceiveGroup#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric"> 
        AND dbo.CS.The_ParentProduct_ID = 0
    End
</cfquery>
```

Now you have ONE query that will either `insert` if it doesn't exists or `update` if it does

Comment: SQL Merge would be cleaner

Comment: THanks @Lance , I was hoping that would do it, but then I got this error: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__OLMS_Dat__9C04DA075F0A3F61'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.OLMS_Data_TempRequests'. The duplicate key value is (1005810264325).

SQL: IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT dbo.OLMS_Data_TempRequests.OLMS_TRequest_ID FROM dbo.OLMS_Data_TempRequests WHERE dbo.OLMS_Data_TempRequests.OLMS_TRequest_ID = (param 1) ) .... bla bla bla.  So even after inserting that if not exists thing, somehow its still throwing errors saying it cant insert!!!!

Comment: @JohnEgbert it sounds as if there is a `key` being sent to the insert statement. If that is the case change the `If exists` part of the query to simply look at the `key` value.  `if not exists (select key from table where key = @key) insert else update`

Comment: This feels to me like it would introduce a race condition unless you enforced a high isolation level.

Comment: THanks Lance , I'll make that change and see if that stabilizes a bit. @TheCycoONE - you might be right...but the environment is highly isolated, the only factor based on the flow of data that should create such a situation is user based (in this case, the execution of bad javascript).  Unfortunately, the pre-existing architecture doesn't allow for UID generation DB side, but its something we're trying to rebuild.  Until then, band-aids left and right :) .  Thanks much, gents!

Answer (score 1):

Your page is probably being submitted twice, like others have said the http log will confirm this, however properly handling double posts is still important.

A strategy I use is to record the post in the session and then reject duplicates.

sending page:

```
<form ...>
   <input type="hidden" name="magicnumber" value="#CreateUUID()#">
</form>
```

receiving page:

```
<cflock scope="session" type="exclusive">
  <cfif StructKeyExists(session.magicnumbers, form.magicnumber)>
    <cfset variables.isdup = true>
  <cfelse>
    <cfset session.magicnumbers[form.magicnumber] = true>
  </cfif>
</cflock>
<cfif !isdup>
...
</cfif>
```

Then I would also use a 303 header to redirect to another page for displaying anything.

Of course you will have to create session.magicnumbers earlier, e.g.  OnSessionStart()
If you are not using user sessions, you can use the application or server scope, but plan to write in some way to trash old values so you don't very slowly eat your memory.

Comment: This is helpful!!  We'll definitely take this into consideration as well!  I haven't thought about doing serialization storage inside a session...